# Automated Update SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, auto-update

I have a table of topics, topics might have an automatic publish date, I want to make SQL Server auto publishes them.

Previously I made it in code on each call to any method of the topics adapter, but I wanna make it automatically in SQL Server.

Can I?

It might be some kinda scheduled job or something like that.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 (Express and Professional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'publish'? It definitely sounds like you could use a [SQL Server Agent job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx), to execute, say

```
UPDATE topics SET published = 1 WHERE publishdate < getdate()
```

if that is what all what you want to do, when you refer to 'auto publish'

**EDIT**

Since a SQL Server Agent job won't do. How about modifying your selects instead?

```
SELECT
   (published OR publishdate < getdate()) as published
FROM
   topics
```

Comment: I linked to SQL Server Agent explanations for you. However, it's worth noting that SQL Server Express doesn't come with SQL Server Agent. You need Standard+ for this.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I know I have to user SQL Server Agent, but as Eric commented, I have SQL Express :(

Is there another way?

Comment: oh. thanks for pointing out. set up a simple windows service, perhaps, that's running in the background and polling the database to execute an sp at a given interval? it's quite simple to do in .net, at least, but no, it's not all-sql.

Comment: (i also added an alternative approach in an edit to this post, but i actually think i'd prefer to go for the win service myself)

Comment: Thanks for the service point, but I'm running the webiste at a remote host that I can't install services on.

I liked the other approach, I'll try to find a way to put it in my code again :)

Thanks.